# How to prevent image recognition of my dataset with neural networks and make it hard to train them?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision, image-recognition, captcha

Suppose I have a private set of images containing some objects.

How do i

1. Make it very hard for the neural networks such as ImageNet to recognize these objects, while allowing humans to do it at the same time?
2. Suppose I label these private images - a picture of a cat with a label "cat" - how do I make it hard for the attacker to train his neural network on my labels? Is it possible to somehow fool a neural network so that they couldn't easily train it to recognize it?

Like random transforms etc, so that they couldn't use a neural network to recognize these objects, or even train it on my dataset if they had labels.

Comment: Just curious, but what's the purpose of this set of images? Are you trying to make your own set of CAPTCHA images (or whatever the image versions of the anti-robot tests are called)?

Answer (score 2):

If the model is trained and held constant, then there are so-called adversarial attacks to modify images such that the model classifies them incorrectly (see *[Attacking Machine Learning
with Adversarial Examples](https://openai.com/blog/adversarial-example-research/)*).

However, if you want to make images that are untrainable, you are probably out of luck. Deep neural networks can learn to recognize even random images with random labels (see *[Understanding deep learning requires rethinking generalization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.03530)*), though if there's no rhyme or reason to the randomness, they won't generalize in meaningful ways.